# Define categories for data element in DHIS2

Tags: dhis-2

Is it possible to create a data element that can take values only in a predefined set of categories *e.g. ‘Not Tested’, ’Result Test: Negative’, ‘Result Test: Positive’* in DHIS2.

Exploring the use of DHIS2 for a dataset of case-based data, or anonymous “patient” data. In the DHIS User Manual, section 1.5: *a variety of details may be recorded, such as the patient’s temperature, their weight, and various blood tests.* 
I understand that it is possible to specify the Value type of a data element as either:

- number
- text
- yes/no
- yes only
- date
- user name

How one would add a custom value type and allow the user to select only in these 3 categories ‘Not Tested’, ’Result Test: Negative’, ‘Result Test: Positive’?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can have custom value type. You need to define option set for example Malaria result and option as ("Not Tested", "Result Test: Negative", "Result Test: Positive"). When you define data element you can select the option set you defined, in this case Malaria Result.

Option sets can be added under apps > data administration > option sets. First define your option set, then click on it, select option management and add your options.